# N/A in the user field event log

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbScript that a user can log an event to the event log bu I need to ensure that the user who logs it populats the **User:** field as part of the event entry. Is there any way to do this? 
If I use this code...

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.LogEvent 4,"This is a message"
```

It logs an event with N/A as the user. Is there any way to ensure that the user who logged the event populates the **User:** field?

Comment: You can at least ask the return value of shell.LogEvent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4ce6by3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: Consider using EventCreate if you are looking for more verbose information. [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490899.aspx)

Comment: Matt, saved me hours of trying to get this working via vbscript/WSH. EventCreate is perfect for what I need. How do I mark your comment as a correct answer? Thanks, Brian